# Check and uncheck checkboxes with different checkbox names

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I need your assistance in solving the issue in the below code. I am having 3 checkboxes. The first checkbox is showing "ALL" and the second one is showing "A" values and the third one is showing  "B" values.

I tried to write a javascript to check and uncheck the textboxes. If the selection is "ALL", then A and B textboxes should be unchecked and if the selection is A or B or both of them, "ALL" should be unchecked. But, the below code is not working when I want to select A or B unless I uncheck ALL.

I do not want to give them the same name, each checkbox has a different name.

```
<form name="test">
    <input type="checkbox" name="c1" id ="ALL" onclick="myFunction()" checked/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="c2" id ="A" onclick="myFunction()"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="c3" id ="B" onclick="myFunction()"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction()
    {
        if ( document.test.c1.checked == true)
        {
            document.getElementById("2").checked = false;
        }
        else if ( document.test.c2.checked == true )
        {
            document.getElementById("1").checked = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Kindly assist me in solving the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you want

```
<input type="checkbox" name="c1" id ="ALL" onclick="myFunction(this)" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="c2" id ="A" onclick="myFunction(this)" />
<input type="checkbox" name="c3" id ="B" onclick="myFunction(this)" />
```

`myFunction()` call is changed to `myFunction(this)`

Javascript is

```
function myFunction(me){
    if( me.checked ){
        if( me.id == "ALL" ){
            document.getElementById("A").checked = false;
            document.getElementById("B").checked = false;
        }
        if( me.id == "A" || me.id == "B" ){
            document.getElementById("ALL").checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```